# Mean of two numbers by infinite sequences

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Consider two numbers $a$ and $b$, and the following sequence alternating between even and odd positions:
$$
a+2b+3a+4b+5a+6b\ldots,
$$
If we ''normalize''
$$
\frac{a+2b+3a+4b+\ldots}{1+2+3+4+\ldots},
$$
it turns out this ratio approaches the mean value of $a$ and $b$: $(a+b)/2$. In general
$$
\frac{a+2^n b+3^n a+4^n b+\ldots}{1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n+\ldots}=\frac{a+b}{2}
$$
for $n\geq1$. However if we use exponential functions instead powers:
$$
\frac{m^1 a+m^2 b+m^3 a+m^4 b+\ldots}{m^1 +m^2 +m^3 +m^4 +\ldots}
$$
for some $m>1$, this ratio oscillates and does not approach any number.

Could someone explain why convergence to the mean is obtained by using sequences of powers, and the ratio diverges for sequences of exponentials?

Comment: Was $|m|<1$ or $|m|>1$ in your experiments? Note also, that you can easily write this as: $$a\frac{m^1+m^3+m^5+\ldots}{m^1 +m^2 +m^3 +m^4 +\ldots}+b\frac{m^2+m^4+m^6+\ldots}{m^1 +m^2 +m^3 +m^4 +\ldots}$$ Do you see the issue? You keep adding larger and larger powers to the $a$ part and to the $b$ part, alternating. Which is probably the cause of oscillations for $|m|>1$

Comment: Yes, I'm using $|m|>1$, but sorry I do not see the issue clearly, why the same argument does not applies to sequences of powers?

Comment: Never mind, apparently there are oscillations whether $|m|>1$ or $|m|<1$. In hindsight, it's easy to see, since we can always divide by largest power of $m$

Comment: @YuriyS wait why oscillations for $|m| < 1$? I agreed with your previous claim that it wouldn't.

For $m > 1$, you could divide by the largest power of $m$, which makes the $m$ case look similar to a $1/m$ case; but you're still adding smaller and smaller terms in the $1/m$ case vs larger and larger terms in the $m$ case (e.g. the largest-coefficient term swaps between $a$ and $b$ in the $m$ case, but it's always $a$ in the $1/m$ case).

Answer (score 3):

To give an evaluation, to make more rigourous, in the first case we have

$$1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n+\ldots+k^n\sim \frac{k^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

$$a+2^n b+3^n a+4^n b+\ldots+k^nb\sim a\left(\frac{k^{n+1}}{n+1}-2^n\frac{k^{n+1}}{(n+1)2^{n+1}}\right)+2^nb\frac{k^{n+1}}{(n+1)2^{n+1}}=$$$$=\frac12(a+b)\frac{k^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

and therefore

$$\frac{a+2^n b+3^n a+4^n b+\ldots+k^nb}{1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n+\ldots+k^n}\sim \frac{\frac12(a+b)\frac{k^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{k^{n+1}}{n+1}}\to \frac{a+b}{2}$$

On the other hand for $m\neq 1$

$$m^1 +m^2 +m^3 +m^4 +\ldots+m^k =\frac{m^{k+1}-m}{m-1}$$

$$m^1 a+m^2 b+m^3 a+m^4 b+\ldots+m^kb\sim a\left(\frac{m^{k}-m}{m-1}-\frac{m^{k}-m^2}{m^2-1}\right)+b\frac{m^{k+2}-m^2}{m^2-1}=$$

$$=a\frac{m^{k+1}-m}{m^2-1}+b\frac{m^{k+2}-m^2}{m^2-1}$$

and therefore

$$\frac{m^1 a+m^2 b+m^3 a+m^4 b+\ldots+m^kb}{m^1 +m^2 +m^3 +m^4 +\ldots+m^k}\sim \frac {a+bm} {m+1}$$

but for

$$m^1 a+m^2 b+m^3 a+m^4 b+\ldots+m^ka$$

we would obtain

$$\frac{m^1 a+m^2 b+m^3 a+m^4 b+\ldots+m^ka}{m^1 +m^2 +m^3 +m^4 +\ldots+m^k}\sim \frac {am+b} {m+1}$$

Comment: A nice answer! Here's the reference to the formula for the sum of powers of integers (for the OP) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula. The geometric sum I'm sure is well known

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks, indeed I had your same idea. for the first part, even if it is not perfectly rigorous, it works fine. What about the second part?

Comment: @ gimusi, I haven't checked yet, I was writing an answer too, but I was too slow. But qualitatively, this seems right. The sequence diverges by oscillations

Comment: @YuriyS Please complete your answer, I want to see that!

Comment: @ gimusi, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks let me know, I'll check it better the derivation in case!

Comment: @ Yuriy S thanks also to you. Numerically I obtain the oscillation between $\tfrac{a+bm}{m+1}$ and $\tfrac{am+b}{m+1}$ as in the gimusi's awnser

Comment: @NessunDorma It is just a rough evaluation to see what it is going on!

Comment: @NessunDorma That's nice! Well done, the work in group always gives the best results!

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm doing something wrong with my calculations, especially since NessunDorma's results agree. In any case, nice question and answer!

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts; not sure if this fully answers "why" but an attempt:

The difference in coefficients of $a$ and $b$ goes roughly like the last coefficient term (whichever one's ahead is ahead by around that much). In the polynomial case this difference becomes small relative to the sums; in the geometric case, this stays large.

This is because last term of a geometric sequence with ratio $m > 1$, no matter how long, is a constant fraction of its sum. But for a polynomial sequence, eventually the last term becomes a vanishingly small fraction of the sum.

---

**More formally**: consider a sequence of positive reals $c_1, c_2, \dots$ (may be geometric, polynomial, whatever). We're interested in

$$\frac{c_1a + c_2b + c_3a + \dots}{c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + \dots}$$

Or more precisely, let the partial sum $s_k = \sum_{1 \le i \le k} c_i$. Let the sum of odd terms $o_k = \sum_{1 \le 2i-1 \le k} c_{2i-1}$ and the sum of even terms $e_k = \sum_{1 \le 2i \le k} c_{2i} = s_k - o_k$. We're interested in

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{o_k a + e_k b}{s_k}$$

Now we can observe this converges for all $a, b$ if and only if $\frac{o_k}{s_k}$ converges.

So the question is: for what kinds of sequences does $\frac{o_k}{s_k}$ converge?

Don't have a nice full answer to this.

But we're more interested in the case when $c_i$ increases it seems, so let's restrict ourselves to that case. Hereafter $c_i$ are **increasing.**

In this case, we can say the following (the formal version of the above)

**Claim**:

(i) if $\frac{c_k}{s_k} \rightarrow 0$ then $\frac{o_k}{s_k} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$.

(ii) if $\frac{o_k}{s_k} \rightarrow L$ then $L = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{c_k}{s_k} \rightarrow 0$.

*Proof of claim*:

Observe first that $\frac{o_k}{s_k} \rightarrow L$ if and only if $\frac{o_k - e_k}{s_k} \rightarrow 2L-1$. In particular $\frac{o_k}{s_k} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow \frac{o_k - e_k}{s_k} \rightarrow 0$

(i) Assume $\frac{c_k}{s_k} \rightarrow 0$. Because the $c_i$ are increasing and positive: when $k$ is odd, $0 \le o_k - e_k \le c_k$. When $k$ is even $0 \le e_k - o_k \le c_k$. So $\left|\frac{o_k - e_k}{s_k}\right| \le \frac{c_k}{s_k}$ for all $k$, hence $\left|\frac{o_k - e_k}{s_k}\right| \rightarrow 0$.

(ii) Assume $\frac{o_k}{s_k} \rightarrow L$. We have $\frac{o_k - e_k}{s_k} \rightarrow 2L-1$. But as in (i) we have $o_k - e_k \ge 0$ for odd $k$ and $o_k - e_k \le 0$ for even $k$. So we must have $2L-1 = 0 \Rightarrow L = 1/2$.

Now let's try to upper bound $\frac{c_k}{s_k}$ in terms of $|\frac{o_k - e_k}{s_k}|$.

For any odd $k$, $(e_{k-1} - o_{k-1}) + (o_k - e_k) = o_k - o_{k-1} = c_k$. Both those terms are positive, so we have that either $\frac{c_k}{2} \le e_{k-1} - o_{k-1} = |o_{k-1} - e_{k-1}|$ or $\frac{c_k}{2} \le o_k - e_k = |o_k - e_k|$. This also holds for even $k$ and can be shown similarly.

So we have

$$c_k \le 2\left(\max \{|o_{k-1} - e_{k-1}|, |o_k - e_k|\}\right)$$

Divide both sides by $s_k$, and we see that the RHS goes to 0 and hence $\frac{c_k}{s_k} \rightarrow 0$ $\square$.

---

**Applied to polynomial case**: so we have $c_1, c_2, \dots = 1^n, 2^n, \dots$. Let's lower bound $s_k$ by some multiple of $k^{n+1}$. Very roughly, note that for say $k \ge 4$,
$$s_k = \sum_{i=1}^k i^n \ge \sum_{i \ge k/2} i^n \ge \sum_{i \ge k/2} \left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^n \ge \lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor \left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^n \ge \frac{k}{4}\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^n = \frac{k^{n+1}}{2^{n+2}}$$
And so $\frac{c_k}{s_k} \le \frac{2^{n+2}}{k} \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

From the claim, this means $\frac{o_k}{s_k} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ and so the sequence of fractions $\frac{o_ka + e_kb}{s_k}$ approaches $\frac{a+b}{2}$ as expected.

**Geometric case**: By the formula for sum of geometric series, we can show that $\frac{c_k}{s_k} = \frac{m^{k-1}}{(m^{k} - 1)/(m - 1)} \ge \frac{m-1}{m}$; hence it cannot go to 0. By the claim, the series of fractions diverges.

[More specifically I think it can be shown that $\frac{o_k}{s_k}$ oscillates between $\frac{1}{m+1}$ and slightly larger than $\frac{m}{m+1}$, using the facts that for even $k$, $e_k = mo_k$ and for odd $k$, $o_k = me_k + c_1$]